# Detect frame change on .GIF

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a client provided .gif file, and using jQuery or plain javascript i need s way to detect every time the picture/frame changes and a way to know what frame its currently on.

Now i can assume the second stage can be a simple counter if someone knows how to detect a frame changing but i would also like to k ow if anyone else knows a better way.

So a bit of context:
- user provides gif, it automatically starts playing,
- a function is called every time the gif changes picture/frame
- the function knows what frame the gif is currently on.

Looked around and couldn't find a question that answers this precisely, only some stuff about canvases, iframes and such which are not possible in the project im doing.

Also i cant be using jquery plugins and such.

Appreciate all help so thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this be of use? [A GIF player in JavaScript](http://slbkbs.org/jsgif/)

Comment: It could work but with a lot of changes, and the fact it runs on a canvas is very suboptimal in my system. Would be better if it wasn't, but if no other suggestions i might have to use it. So thanks!

Comment: I don't see how else you would detect it than by comparing the data state on a canvas: it's an image; it has no readable text data.